# Dirichlet character over Riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character mod q and let $$L(s,\chi)=\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}.$$ What is the value of $\displaystyle\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{L(s,\chi)}{\zeta(s)}$ for principal character $\chi_0$ and non-principal characters $\chi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For $\chi \neq \chi_0$ $L(s,\chi)$ is analytic for $\text{Re}(s)>0$ (by partial summation) so that in particular $L(1,\chi)$ is finite.  $\zeta(s)$ has a pole with residue $1$ at $s=1$ which can be shown by looking at $\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}$ which will be analytic for $\text{Re}(s)>1$.  For $\chi_0$, $L(s,\chi_0)$ is almost the same as $\zeta(s)$.  In particular by using Euler products we can write $$L(s,\chi_0)=\zeta(s)\prod_{p|q} \left(1-p^{-s}\right).$$

From this we can conclude that if $\chi $ is non principal, the limit is $0$, and if it is principal then the limit is $\frac{\phi (q)}{q}$.